# Environment variables are not being read in django/docker environment

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am running a dockerized django app and would like to pass my AWS credentials into my settings.py. So I set my environment variables in my .bash_profile and then in settings.py I do: `os.getenv[AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID]`. I also tried `os.environ[...]`.

When I enter my shell for debugging I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    667         except KeyError:
    668             # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 669             raise KeyError(key) from None
    670         return self.decodevalue(value)
```

So i figure the environment variable is None, thus is not read. Is that a problem with docker/bash? I mean that it is not accessible? Or should it be? Or do I have to set it in my Dockerfile? If so, how?

Any hint or help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

And I run my docker with: `docker-compose -f local.yml up`
I build it with `docker-compose -f local.yml build`

Comment: Could you show your docker file? Could you also show how you run the container?

Comment: `docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX  -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX myimage` or add `ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID XXXXX`to your dockerfile

Comment: thanks Ferrybig! Absolutely I updated my question

Comment: thanks LinPy, will try!

Comment: yes it will add it to your container at run time, if you want it in build time use `ARG` also

Comment: if I do this and then enter my shell it still throws me the same error. Also is there a way of not having it in the dockerfile? Because I push that to git and I don't want it in the history

Comment: that : docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX myimage

Comment: But this I have to put every time I build the container anew right?

Comment: when I run this I get ```REDIS_URL: parameter not set``` even though it is set